# Good resource to explain Lambda Expression syntax to newbie?

Tags: .net, linq, lambda

Lambda expressions seem to be a common stumbling block to those new to .NET. Does anyone have a good resource for explaining them to newbies?

Comment: are you the newbie? can I be the source?

Comment: Do they? I also don't think that lambda expressions *per se* are something .net-specific, they are normal part of functional programming. More of that, lambda expressions are not part of .net, they are part of some languages in it, CLR does not have a notion of them.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt I'm guessing he's not the newbie since he just posted a link to his blog that explains them in detail.  "Self?"  "Yes, Self."  "I have a question."  "That's great, Self.  I have an answer to your question!"

Comment: @Dan lol to be fair i asked that before he posted that :P

Comment: Not an appropriate use of SO to post a question just so you can answer it.

Comment: Forgive me. I misunderstood the checkbox stating "Answer your own question - share your knowledge, Q&A-style" when asking a question. I was trying to share my knowledge. I know for the future now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda is simply an anonymous method like this:

```
delegate(string parm1, int parm2)
{
    // ...
}
```

The first part of a lambda is for the method parameters.  If there are no parameters, or if there are more than one parameter, parentheses are required:

```
// no parameters
() => null

// one parameter
x => null

// multiple parameters
(x, y, z) => null
```

A lambda corresponding to the anonymous method above would be written:

```
(string parm1, int parm2) => ...
```

Depending on how the lambda is used, the compiler can actually infer the types of the parameters and the return value, so they aren't always required.

The last part of a lambda is for the method body.

```
delegate(string parm1, int parm2)
{
    return string.Format("{0}{1}", parm1, parm2);
}
```

is the same as

```
(parm1, parm2) =>
{
    return string.Format("{0}{1}", parm1, parm2);
}
```

If the body of the method is a single line, the lambda does not require a return keyword, nor curly braces:

```
(parm1, parm2) => string.Format("{0}{1}", parm1, parm2);
```

Those are the basics.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Lambda is not anonymous method. Lambda *can be* treated as anonymous method, but, for example, all `Queryable` extensions do not use anonymous (or any other) methods, but still greatly profit from lamdbas.

Comment: I disagree with you saying that lambdas are not anonymous methods.  In .Net, they are.  The C# compiler compiles lambdas and anonymous methods down to IL the same way.  In .Net, lambdas were implemented with anonymous methods.

Comment: You're wrong here. While `Enumerable.Where(source, a => a.Name == "")` has second parameter of type `Func<T,bool>` which *is* a delegate and will produce an anonymous method, `Queryable.Where(source, a => a.Name == "")` has second parameter of type `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` and thus is *not* a delegate and will produce not a method, but *expression tree*, which can be later used by `QueryableProvider`. That's how Entity Framework, Linq2Sql and so on work.

Comment: BTW, that's why `var f = b => b.Name == "";` won't compile. If lambdas were delegates, type of expression would be easily inferrable.

Comment: I stand corrected.  BUT, delving into the intricacies of Expression Trees and how they relate to lambdas, /probably/ isn't the best way to go about explaining lambdas to a noob.  That's more of an advanced topic.

Comment: In my experience that's the only thing that needs explaining. All the others are just syntax sugar. As both answers to this post show, it is very important to tell syntax from implementation, and delegate from expression.

Comment: Well, that's good for you then.  I accept that you have an opinion.